# Azure Repos - allow co-workers to submit without pushing

Tags: azure, push-notification, authorization, push, commit

I created an Azure repos (the first of my life ;-) and I have invited people to work on the project. They have a microsoft account. This is the free Azure environment.

I want to be notified when they submit their work and accept or reject it before I accept to commit the modification in the branches.

I am confused about the amount of working group options and I did not found the way to do what I want!

Does someone know what configuration must be done with their accounts / the Azure authorizations ?

Comment: Hi, I found a partial answer :

Comment: Hi, I found a partial answer :
In my internet explorer, I go to the Azure project settings and in the left column, I click on repositories. Then, I can change the authorizations given to the groups - developpers.

I can now allow contributors to check in but if I do so, they can check in and I have no way to accept or reject the modification. In the other way, if I select deny to push in, they cannot push anything at all...

Comment: Options are :Administer labels
,Check in,
Check in other users' changes
,Label
,Lock
,Manage branch
,Manage permissions
,Merge
,Pend a change in a server workspace
,Read
,Revise other users' changes
,Undo other users' changes
,Unlock other users' changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found :
Go to the Azure project settings and in the left column, click on repositories. Then, change the authorizations given to the groups - developpers. You can now allow contributors to check in but if you do so, they can check in and I have no way to accept or reject the modification. In the other way, if you select deny to push in, they cannot push anything at all.

Git on azure allows for code validation before to commit. TFS Doesn't. A work around is to create a pullrequest folder where contributors are allowed to push in and be notified each time someone pushes their code in it. Verify and then merge / push in the corresponding branch.